# Is the ratio of the Cameron-Martin-norm and Banach-norm bounded on Banach-norm bounded sets?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

In my efforts to better understand abstract Wiener spaces, the following question came up:

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with norm $\left\lVert  \cdot \right\rVert_{H}$ and take another, weaker norm $\left\lVert \cdot  \right\rVert_{B}$ on $H$ (i.e. $\left\lVert h \right\rVert_B \leq \left\lVert h \right\rVert_H$ for all $h \in H$).
Completing $H$ with respect to $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_B$ yields a separable Banach space $B$, in which $H$ is continuously and densely embedded.

**Question 1:** If $\left\lVert b - h_n \right\rVert_B \to 0$, where $b \in B\setminus H$ and $(h_n)\subseteq H$, it should always follow that $\left\lVert h_n \right\rVert_H \to \infty$. Is this correct? If so, why?

**Question 2** (very related to question 1): What can one say about $\sup_{x \in H, \left\lVert x \right\rVert_B \leq 1} \left\lVert x \right\rVert_H = \sup_{x \in H} \frac{\left\lVert x \right\rVert_H}{\left\lVert x \right\rVert_B}$? Is this always infinite?

**Question 3:** Do the answers to question 1 and 2 change if $(i,H,B)$ forms an abstract Wiener space ($i$ being the injection of $H$ into $B$) and if needed the corresponding Gaussian measure is non-degenerate? If I understand correctly, to obtain an abstract Wiener space from the above construction, one needs to make assumptions on $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_{B}$, for example that it is measurable in the sense of Gross.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please show your effort.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Well, I don't know if I'm on the right track but for question one, assuming (to get a contradiction) that $\left\lVert h_n \right\rVert_{H} \leq C$ for all $n$, we can extract a subsequence which is convergent in $H$- and in $B$-norm simultaneously. The limit in $H$-norm must lie in $H$ as $H$ is complete, so if we knew that it coincides with the limit in $B$-norm, this would yield a contradiction. However, in general the limits can be different, can't they?